# Help Calculating $F'(x_0)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, partial-derivative

> Given: $$F(x) = \int_{2-x^{0.5}}^{x^4} \frac{\arctan(y/x)}{y}dy$$
> Calculate $F'(4)$ or ($lim x-> 4$ if $F'(4)$ not defined)

I was given that if: $G(x)=\int_{u(x)}^{v(x)} g(x,y)dy$ then $G(x_0)=\int_{u(x_0)}^{v(x_0)} g(x_0,y)dy$

In my case I get:
$F(4) = \int_{0}^{4^4} \frac{\arctan(y/4)}{y}dy$ So, $F'(4) = \left(\int_{0}^{4^4} \frac{\arctan(y/4)}{y}dy\right)'$

I tried using Leibniz's rule but I get that the derivative is **always** o,

which is wrong. What's my mistake and May someone correct me?

Comment: $F^{\prime}(4)$ means differentiate $F$ with respect to $x$, **then** substitute $x=4$. You substituted $x=4$ first, then differentiated, which is wrong. Just as in a simple case: if $f(x) = x^2$, then $f^{\prime}(4) = 2(4) = 8$, not $\left(4^2\right)^{\prime} = 0$.

Comment: @Prasiortle But If I can't write x_0=4 then how the given would help at all. you are telling me to do the normal calculation and not to pay attention to what is given.

Comment: You should differentiate the given with respect to $x$ using the Leibniz integral rule. This gives $F^{\prime}(x) = \frac{\arctan(x^4/x)}{x^4}(4x^3) - \frac{\arctan\left(\left(2-x^{0.5}\right)/x\right)}{2-x^{0.5}}(-0.5x^{-0.5})+\int_{2-x^{0.5}}^{x^4}\frac{\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2}\cdot\left(-\frac{y}{x^2}\right)}{y}\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}y$. Then set $x=4$.

Answer (score 1):

$G(x)=\int_u^vg(x,y)dy=h(x,v)-h(x,u)$, so $G'(x)=\frac{\partial h(x,v)}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial h(x,v)}{\partial v}\frac{dv}{dx}-\frac{\partial h(x,u)}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial h(x,u)}{\partial u}\frac{du}{dx}=\int_u^v\frac{\partial g(x,y)}{\partial x}dy+g(v,x)\frac{dv}{dx}-g(u,x)\frac{du}{dx}$

I'll let you finish.